# Ping/tracert works, but not browser or any windows programs. Tried USB WiFi and reformatted already

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, browser, internet-connection, ping

My laptop used to work fine. My girlfriend was moving to California for a month, so I gave it to her to take with her. It worked fine the day before she left. Once she got there, it wouldn't work. However, she was staying with her sister who was using WEP and refused to switch to WPA, so I suspected that was the issue or that she was giving my girlfriend the wrong passcode.

Now she's back, and the laptop is definitely broken. I am able to "ping google.com", or any domain for that matter, and it resolves just fine. Tracert works as well with any domain, so I'm pretty sure it's not a DNS issue. I've tried pointing the browser to the IP address that showed up when I pinged google.com in the command prompt. I tried:

```
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /renew
netsh winsock reset
```

However, since I reformatted and tried a USB WiFi card, and the problem is still exactly the same, I'm beginning to believe it's a motherboard problem. It's an "ASUS N61JQ-XV1". It's taken a few falls in its days, mostly from the top of the bed onto the carpet, nothing major, and it has always worked fine after. I'm wondering if it was just barely still working when I sent her off, and it got jarred around on the plane or something and finally broke. However, it's strange that pinging works fine but not the browser, or any Windows program for that matter.

Here's the result of ping, tracert, and ipconfig /all:

ping:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Brett>ping google.com

Pinging google.com [74.125.224.200] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 74.125.224.200: bytes=32 time=23ms TTL=56
Reply from 74.125.224.200: bytes=32 time=24ms TTL=56
Reply from 74.125.224.200: bytes=32 time=23ms TTL=56
Reply from 74.125.224.200: bytes=32 time=24ms TTL=56

Ping statistics for 74.125.224.200:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 23ms, Maximum = 24ms, Average = 23ms
```

tracert:

```
C:\Users\Brett>tracert google.com

Tracing route to google.com [74.125.224.200]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  192.168.1.1
  2     9 ms    18 ms    10 ms  10.128.16.1
  3     8 ms    17 ms     9 ms  172.21.1.70
  4    23 ms    15 ms    13 ms  70.169.73.66
  5    10 ms    11 ms    14 ms  mcdldsrj01-ae2.0.rd.ph.cox.net [70.169.76.225]
  6    23 ms    24 ms    25 ms  langbprj02-ae2.rd.la.cox.net [68.1.1.19]
  7    25 ms    23 ms    23 ms  72.14.215.221
  8    23 ms    24 ms    28 ms  209.85.248.185
  9    27 ms    22 ms    23 ms  72.14.236.13
 10    32 ms    24 ms    23 ms  lax02s02-in-f8.1e100.net [74.125.224.200]

Trace complete.
```

ipconfig /all:

```
C:\Users\Brett>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Brett-ASUS
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Ethernet adapter Bluetooth Network Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 74-F0-6D-A9-5F-F4
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 48-5D-60-3A-B6-77
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::c9b2:3383:74ca:6a0b%12(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.6(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Saturday, March 23, 2013 12:33:18 PM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Sunday, March 24, 2013 12:33:20 PM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 222846304
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-18-DF-18-19-20-CF-30-4A-7C-F6

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Atheros AR8131 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Con
troller (NDIS 6.20)
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 20-CF-30-4A-7C-F6
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{6554A3E0-2B38-40EF-8710-AB2817229625}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:9d38:953c:289d:37e5:bb1b:6fb(Prefe
rred)
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::289d:37e5:bb1b:6fb%16(Preferred)
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.{C945B74D-7506-4F78-92F0-62BDA7244A17}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

C:\Users\Brett>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to start ruling things out. Since you're re-intalled after a reformat, it isn't the OS.  Since you're able to ping, you've established that your network card can send and receive data.  That also means your motherboard is fine.

After the clean install of Windows, did you test before installing any other third-party software, such as Virus Scan, Firewalls, etc?

In what way is your browser/windows applications "broken"?  You say you tried putting in Google's IP address into the browser.  What result did you get? A blank page, 404 Error, some other error?

One possibility is that your router has content filtering enabled, or a mis-configured port forwarding rule.  Have you been playing with your router configuration?  Do you have any port forward rules for port 80?

A way to rule out your router configuration is to test that you are able to get HTTP data through your network card.  You can use Telnet from the command line to test this:

```
$> telnet www.google.com 80 <enter>
GET / HTTP/1.1 <enter><enter>
```

You should get the contents of a web page.  If not, something outside of your computer is allowing some kinds of network traffic but limiting others, such as HTTP traffic.  Things to look at would be your router, or an upstream proxy server.

Comment: It's a clean install with no software or anything added. Just windows 7. We have another laptop, a desktop, an Apple TV, an iPad, and two iPhones. Everything else works fine. The laptop worked fine before I sent it with her to CA. It has never worked since she left my place, never worked in CA. Haven't changed any router settings. When I try to access any website on Internet explorer, it times out. I'm not home now so I'll test more when I get back and let you know.

Comment: Ok I tried telnet and it said could not connect or something like that. Also, I'm able to access and browse the laptop from my desktop, but not vice versa. I don't think it's a router issue, because every other device on the network works fine, and no changes have been made to router config. Also, the problem started when the laptop was in California on a different router.